# Android Studio error, column name doesnt exit even though it is created?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

This is the error i am encountering :

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) table contacts has no column named name in "INSERT
> INTO contacts(phone_number,name) VALUES (?,?)" E/SQLiteDatabase: Error
> inserting phone_number=22222 name=Name

And here the code running the database which consists of 2 columns, 1 for name and phone number:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String create = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(create2);
}  

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

   void addContact(Contact c) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, c.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, c.getPhoneNumber());
// Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

I made sure that the contact class isnt returning null.

Comment: Uninstall the app from the device and rerun. If the problem persists try in a clean device.

Comment: You're executing `create2` but the sql is in `create`.